# How can I rename files in folders, while keeping part of the name unchanged?

Tags: command-line, find, rename

I have multiple files (about 1000) named as such:

```
db_1582779454_1582778086_69_2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA
db_1582037529_1579666328_6_03C074E4-6BB9-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C
db_1582037529_1579666328_6_03C074E4-9AA0-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C
```

want to rename these folders recursively by changing the end values

```
2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA
03C074E4-6BB9-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C
03C074E4-9AA0-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C
```

To a new value

```
2AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA
Final folder names = db_1582779454_1582778086_69_2AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA
```

I tried

```
find -iname . -exec rename -n 's/(db\_\d+\_\d+\_\d+\_)03C074E4-6BB9-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C/$12AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA/' {} \;
```

thanks

Comment: Your "numbers" contain letters. Hexadeximal digits? So your pattern won't match.

Comment: You first refer to 'files', then 'folders'. Which are they? When does recursion come in?  The pattern you show is: `db_<same>_<same>_<same>_<changed>-<cahnged>-<same>-<same>`. Is that right? Are the changed values arbitrary or being comptued? Edit your quesiton to clarify, please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called file.list with the filenames.

Run this for loop:

for FL in $(cat file.list)
do
NEWFL=$(echo $FL | cut -f5 -d'_')
echo "Old: $FL, New: $NEWFL"
done

This produces the output:

Old: db_1582779454_1582778086_69_2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA, New: 2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA
Old: db_1582037529_1579666328_6_03C074E4-6BB9-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C, New: 03C074E4-6BB9-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C
Old: db_1582037529_1579666328_6_03C074E4-9AA0-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C, New: 03C074E4-9AA0-434A-B95D-4FE29787060C

You can substitute the "echo command with a mv command"

New info:

You could separate the prefix and suffix of each name like this:

for FL in $(cat file.list)
do
PREFIX=$(echo $FL | cut -f1-4 -d'_')
SUFFIX=$(echo $FL | cut -f5 -d'_')
echo "Filename: $FL, Prefix: $PREFIX, Suffix: $SUFFIX"
done

From there, you could rename using:

mv $FL $PREFIX_$NEWSUFFIX

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Vince Sh but final should be something like db_1582779454_1582778086_69_2AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA instead of db_1582779454_1582778086_69_2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA

2AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA in the folder/directory name gets changed to 2BB5873B-84B0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA

Comment: Sorry Dixxyyy, I misread the requirement. I thought you were trying to cut off the first part.  Do you know what each file/folder name will be, or is there some formula you are following?

Comment: Yes VInce each file name will have something (db\_\d+\_\d+\_\d+\_)<GUID, but i want to replace all the GUIDs for that directory

Rename from db_<newest_time><oldest_time><bucketid>_<old_guid's> to db_<newest_time><oldest_time><bucketid>_<guid>

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
export replaceby='_2AE5873D-84C0-424B-9A1A-F648EE7CD5FA'
find . -type f -name "db_*_*_*_*-*-*-*-*" -exec sh -c '
    for file in "$@"; do
        #You may want to make a backup statement here
        mv "$file" "${file%_*}${replaceby}"
    done
' find-shell {} +
```

The `replaceby` variable was used just for clarity, you could simply use its value directly in the `mv` statement.

Notice that the 2nd and 3rd files you provided would become the same final file, because they have the same name until the last underscore. Which means **3rd file will overwrite the 2nd**. You can (should?) add a backup statement before `mv`, such as `cp "$file" "${file}.bak"`, in case any such thing goes wrong.

---

About the `${file%_*}` construct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952009